# How do I get Visual Studio 2013 to stop indenting the contents of the script tag?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, indentation, code-formatting, auto-indent

When using the HTML/Web Forms editor in Visual Studio 2013, it keeps automatically indenting the contents of my  tags. In previous versions of Visual Studio, I could do the following:

```
open Options -> Text Editor -> HTML (Web Forms) -> Formatting 
click "Tag Specific Options"
then open "Client HTML tags"
click on "script" 
and uncheck "Indent contents".
```

I've done this in VS 2013, but it keeps indenting every time I enter a new line/paste/etc.